How to deal with large OnModelCreating function in Entity Framework?
We want to use a custom primary key constraint name of pk_users_id instead of generated by Entity Framework PK_Users by default. There is no attribute for this and we have to use fluent api. We have such DbContext file:
    public class AppDbContext: DbContext {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder
                .Entity<UserEntity>()
                .HasKey(user => user.Id)
                .HasName("pk_users_is");

            // here would be thousands of lines for other entities
        
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
    }

The first thing, that comes to mind would be creating static method on each entity and then call it for each entity, like this:
    public class UserEntity {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        public static void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserEntity> builder) {
            builder
                .HasKey(user => user.Id)
                .HasName("pk_users_id");
        }
    }

    public class AppDbContext: DbContext {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            UserEntity.Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>());

            // here call Configure for every entity, similarly as above

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
    }

However, using static properties like that is an anti-pattern.
What could be a reasonable way to keep each entity configuration in fluent api, that can't be achieved with attributes, near the entity, rather than everything in OnModelCreating?

Can you tag your UserEntity class with a custom attribute, and then use reflection in OnModelCreating to look for the attribute and grab the name of the desired key?

Edit: This applies to EF Core, for EF6 (.Net Framework) there is the EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> class which can be extended which does the same thing.
I use attributes then IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> to handle relationships and stuff that isn't intuitive/available through attributes. For example:
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public const string EmployeeIdFK = "EmployeeId";

    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.EmployeeDetail)
            .WithOne(x => x.Employee)
            .HasForeignKey<EmployeeDetail>(EmployeeIdFK);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<User>(EmployeeIdFK);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Positions)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(EmployeeIdFK);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Enquiries)
            .WithOne(x => x.Employee)
            .HasForeignKey(EmployeeIdFK);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.EmployeeAlerts)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(EmployeeIdFK);
    }
}

Then when configuring the DbContext:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(Employee).Assembly))
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

You can put the entity type configs under a /Configuration folder alongside or underneath your Entities, or use VS 2022's nesting naming support such as naming the file Employee.configuration.cs where VS can nest the file underneath the Employee.cs class file.

Why I prefer fluent API above Attributes
Class MyDbContext represents your database management system. The DbSet<T> properties represent the tables in the database. The <T> part represents the type of one row in the table.
The non-virtual properties in <T> represent the actual columns of the table, the virtual properties represent the relations between tables: one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.
Having defined this, you could think that your T might be used in several databases, each with its own configuration. For instance, in one database your decimals might have a different precision than in the other database. Or in one database the description of a product might be emtpy, while in another database it may not.
These constraints are typically constraints for the used database.
When using attributes to define these constraints, you can't reuse T for your other database.
Son instead of Attributes I prefer fluent API
Consider class Product using Attributes:
(As said, I don't use Attributes, so I might use incorrect Attributes, but you'll get the gist)
[Table("table_Products")]
class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength[250]
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public int Stock {get; set;}
    [Precision(10, 3)]
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}

The use of these attributes makes reuse impossible in another database where you want a different table name, you don't require a description and you want a different precision for your decimals.
Using fluent API makes your product class much cleaner. This is the class that the users of your code will see way more often than method DbContext.OnModelCreating
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public int Stock {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}

Of course, if you don't use Attributes you'll have to use OnModelCreating:
public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
public DbSet<Order> Orders {get; set;}
... // other DbSets

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    this.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Product>);
    this.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Order>);
    base.OnModelCreating();
}

private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> products)
{
    // fluent API to define table name, primary key, decimal precision, etc
}

private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> products)
{
    // fluent API to define table name for Products,
    // primary key, decimal precision, etc
}

private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<Order> orders)
{
    // fluent API to define configuration for table Orders,
}

Class Product looks way more simpler, it can be used in different databases, you can even use class Product for rows in a CSV file, or to display in a DataGridView.
DbContext represents the database, so that is the place where you should define the configuration of the database that it represents.
Back to your question
Ok, so your OnModelCreating contains a lot of DbSets, and hundreds of lines.
By separating the model creation in methods per table (EntityType), you make OnModelCreating at least way more readable. People who need to find the model creation lines for class Product will immediately find it.
Your problem is, that a lot of classes need the same configuration. For instance, most, if not all tables have a key in property Id, which has the name "pk_users_id". (Is it me, I couldn't find method EntityTypeBuilder<T>.HasName).
So, for example, your database has tables with Products, Customers and Orders, and you need to set the key and Name as described.
class OrderingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get; set;}
    ... // other DbSets

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        this.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Product>);
        this.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Order>);
        this.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>);
        base.OnModelCreating();
    }

I split OnModelCreating into several methods, one method for every table.
    private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> products)
    {
        // call the common part for most tables: set the Id and the Name
        this.DefineKey(products, product => product.Id);

        // configure the rest of the key table
        // Property Name is required and has a max length of 30
        products.Property(product => product.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

        // property Description is optional, and has a max length of 250
        products.Property(product => product.Description)
                .IsOptional()
                .HaxMaxLength(250);
    }

    private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<Order> orders)
    {
        // call the common part for most tables: set the Id and the Name
        this.DefineKey(products, product => product.Id);

        ... // configure the other properties of class Order
    }

The common method used by most, if not all, tables: DefineKey:
    // method to set a property as Key and to define pk_user_id as key name
    private void DefineKey<TEntityType, TKey>(
        EntityTypeConfiguration<T> entityType,
        Expression<Func<TEntityType,TKey>> keyExpression)
    {
        const string defaultKeyName = "pk_users_id";
        this.DefineKey(entityType, keyExpression, defaultKeyName);
    }

    // method to set a property as Key and to define the key name
    private void DefineKey<TEntityType, TKey>(
        EntityTypeConfiguration<T> entityType,
        Expression<Func<TEntityType,TKey>> keyExpression,
        string keyName)
   {
       entityType.HasKey(keyExpression);
       entityType.Property(keyExpression)
                 .HasColumnName(keyName);
       // install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational for this method
   }
}

What I did:

For every Table I created a method `OnModelCreating(EntityTypeConfiguration<...> x)
In this method I define the configuration for the table: name, key, etc
I use EntityTypeBuilder<T>.Property to define the configuration of the property (maxLength, column name, column type
I use one method DefineKey to define the items for the key. This method is used by most, if not all tables.

When caling DefineKey, I had to provide the property in which the key is set: this.DefineKey(products, product => product.Id). This has the advantage that if one of your classes has a different property for the key, for instance ProductId, you can simply use this.DefineKey(product, product => product.ProductId).
However, if you are absolutely certain that all your tables will have the same property for the Id, I'd enforce this by creating an interface.
interface IKey
{
    int Id {get;}
}

class Product : IKey {...}
class Order : IKey {...}

Now it is impossible for someone to define a different property as key, or the compiler will complain.
private void DefineKey<TEntityType> where TEntityType : IKey(
        EntityTypeConfiguration<T> entityType)
{
    this.DefineKey(entityType, entity -> entity.Id);
}

